# Rotate matrix in THREE js

Tags: matrix, three.js, rotation

I have to construct object worldmatrix manually because this is faster and a lot more optimal than using the methods to set position. But the problem i have is that i need to rotate the matrix 180 degrees. makeRotationY(alpha) just sets the rotation to 180 disregarding the pre-existing rotation.I need to be able to retain the pre-existing rotation. So if matrix has rotation 10 and i apply 180 rotation the total is 190. How can i do this?

It currently works like this:

```
   var inverse_view_to_source = new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse(camera.matrix).
   multiply(src_portal.matrix);
   inverse_view_to_source.makeRotationY(Math.PI);
   inverse_view_to_source = dst_portal.matrix.clone().multiply(inverse_view_to_source);
```